# jQuery cycle plugin - Stopping

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I have my page setup to start an automatic scroll of images (with the cycle plugin) when you hover over it's category link. That works fine. What I want now is to have the automatic cycling stop when you hover off the link and then to start the manual 'next/prev' slideshow.

Basically, when you hover over the category link, cycle through the images. When you hover off, stop the slideshow and use the next/prev buttons to manually view the images.

I can't, however, get the slideshow to stop when the user hovers off the link. I need someway to kill the plugin then reinitialize it with the new options (the manual scroll).

How can I go about doing this?
Cycle plugin I'm talking about: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

The Cycle plugin has [pause & resume methods](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pause.html) which may achieve what you're after.

Also, if you browse through the list of [Additional Demos](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/more.html?v2.23) you'll find many examples of interacting with running slideshows programmatically.